# How to localize data array in plugin's option page

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, wp-localize-script

So i am localizing data saved in an array for my plugin's options, however the data is only localized in the front end, how can I localize data in the plugin's option page as well?

The following is what I use to print the data in the front end to be used by my jquery script,

```
/* localize array data */
    $data = get_option('lu_ban_data'); 
    wp_localize_script( 'lu_ban', 'lu_ban_object', $data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am missing the point but assuming that a script is enqueued with the `lu_ban` slug...

```
function add_data_admin_wpse_112178() {
    $data = get_option('lu_ban_data');
    wp_localize_script( 'lu_ban', 'lu_ban_object', $data);
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','add_data_admin_wpse_112178');
```